# How to evaluate GF(256) element

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I wonder is there any easy way to evaluate elements of GF$(256)$: meaning that I would like to know what $\alpha^{32}$ or $\alpha^{200}$ is in polynomial form? I am assuming that the primitive polynomial is  $D^8+D^4+D^3+D^2+1$. For example for GF$(8)$ what we do is as follow to calculate $\alpha^3$ is divide it by $\alpha^3+\alpha+1$ and we get $\alpha+1$ but here in GF$(256)$ this will be really tedious so I would like to know is there any way to calculate above expressions or similar expressions like $\alpha^{100}$ in GF$(256)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Just so we're clear here, $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$ and you want some kind of algorithm/formula to figure out how to calculate powers of $\alpha$ quickly. Is that correct?

Comment: Here D^8+D^4+D^3+D^2+1 is the primitive polynomial that is used to generate elements of GF(256) and Yes I need to be able to calculate powers alpha. You know like my example alpha ^3 is equal to alpha+1. The reason why I need it because I would like to convert them to decimal therefore alpha+1 is like 3 if alpha itself is 2 so I can actually convert the polynomial notation to binary or decimal notation.

Comment: Consider using repeated squaring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: @stewbasic I used your idea in my answer.

Comment: You can use square-and-multiply, you can try and use a normal basis or... If you need to implement this in a computer program, I really recommend that you build a discrete logarithm table and an anti-logarithm table in the beginning. That reduces calculation of products to sums of integers modulo 255 together with a table look up.
See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591253/11619) for examples involving smaller fields. Anyway, you will benefit from having precalculated $D^8,D^9,D^{10},D^{11},D^{12},D^{13},D^{14}$ because squaring can be done term-by-term.

Answer (score 4):

GF$(256)$ is small enough that you should construct an *antilog* table for it and save it for later reference rather than compute the polynomial form of $\alpha^{32}$ or $\alpha^{100}$ on the fly each time you need it. The
computer version of the *antilog* table is an array that stores the polynomial forms for $1 (= \alpha^0), \alpha, \alpha^2, \cdots, \alpha^{254}$ in locations $0, 1, 2, \cdots, 254$. For human use, the table
is constructed with two columns and looks something like this
$$\begin{array}{r|l}
\hline\\
i & \alpha^i \text{ equals}\\
\hline\\
0 & 00000001\\
1 & 00000010\\
2 & 00000100\\
3 & 00001000\\
4 & 00010000\\
5 & 00100000\\
6 & 01000000\\
7 & 10000000\\
8 & 00011101\\
9 & 00111010\\
10 & 01110100\\
11 & 11101000\\
12 & 11001101\\
\vdots & \vdots\quad \vdots \quad \vdots\\
254 & 10001110\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
The $i$-th entry in the second column is the polynomial representation
of $\alpha^i$ in abbreviated format. For  example, $\alpha^8$ is stated to be equal to $00011101$ which is shorthand for $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1$.
The entry for $\alpha^i$ is obtained by shifting the entry
immediately above by one place to the left (inserting a $0$ on the
right) and if there is an $\alpha^8$ term thus formed, removing it
and adding $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1$ (i.e. XORing $00011101$)
into the 
rightmost $8$ bits. This process is easy to mechanize to produce
the antilog table by computer rather than by hand (which can be tedious
and mistake-prone).

Comment: This is the method I always use (though for fields of rather smaller cardinality).

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** None of the following Python code has been tested. Furthermore, it's not real code but rather pseudo-code adapted to Python in order to explain a rigorous algorithm while making it readable as possible to people who don't know code or don't know Python.

Wikipedia has [a very helpful algorithm for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field) and it is about the exact field you are dealing with. Let $\mathbf a$ be the first multiplicand and $\mathbf b$ be the second multiplicand. Now, initialize $\mathbf p=0$. At the end, the variable $\mathbf p$ will have the product. Wikipedia describes with more detail into the binary bit manipulations with this algorithm than I do, but here's the pseudo-Python code:

```
function multiply(a, b):
    p = 0
    # Loop through this eight times, once for each term in b:
    repeat 8 times:
        # If b's constant term is 1, then add p by a:
        if coefficient(b, 1) == 1: p += a
        # Now, we've taken care of this term by a.
        # Therefore, get rid of the constant term of b and divide b by x:
        b -= coefficient(b, 1)
        b //= x

        # carry stores the leading coefficient of a.
        carry = coefficient(a, x^7)
        # Now, get rid of the x^7 term and multiply a by x:
        a -= coefficient(a, x^7)*x^7
        a *= x
        # Now, in order to deal with the loss of the x^7 term,
        # which would now be an x^8 term since we multiplied by x,
        # if carry had a value of 1, then we need to add x^4+x^3+x^2+1.
        # We do this because x^8=x^4+x^3+x^2+1 in this field.
        if carry == 1: a += x^4+x^3+x^2+1

    # Finally, return the product:
    return p
```

Now, we need to combine this with [@stewbasic's idea of exponentiation by squaring](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/197161/stewbasic):

```
function exponentiation(alpha, power):
    answer = 1
    # This represents alpha to the current power of 2.
    # At the beginning, the first power of 2 is 2^0=1, so alpha^1=alpha.
    alpha_to_power = alpha
    # Loop through this eight times, once for each bit in power.
    # We assume power is an eight bit number since alpha^256=1.
    repeat 8 times:
        # If the last bit of power is 1, then multiply alpha_to_power to answer:
        if last_bit(power) == 1: answer = multiply(answer, alpha_to_power)
        # Right shift power in order to get rid of the last bit:
        power >>= 1

        # Then, square alpha_to_power
        # in order to advance to the next power of 2:
        alpha_to_power = multiply(alpha_to_power, alpha_to_power)

    # Finally, return the answer:
    return answer
```

For some $GF(2^m)$, the `multiply` function has a `for` loop of `m` and the `exponentiation` function has a `for` loop of `m` in which the `multiply` function is called 1-2 times each loop around. Therefore, this is a $O(m^2)$ algorithm, which is quite reasonable for your case of $m=8$.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic with polynomials — including things like divisibility and modular arithmitic — is closely analogous to arithmetic with integers, and many of the same methods apply.

In particular, consider the standard techniques for doing similar computations in the integers, e.g. as described at [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand).